# It has the google-cloud package installed, but it cannot pull the texttotext module in the package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-language

```
import os
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud import texttotext
```

error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'texttotext' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I'm new to the software, what could be wrong?

I want to make a text bot that connects to the Bard AI and prints text.

pip list :
google-cloud 0.34.0
google-cloud-dialogflow 2.25.0
google-cloud-language 2.11.1
google-cloud-texttospeech 2.14.2
python version 3.11.3
I got help from bard artificial intelligence while writing the code.

Comment: Are you sure that import is written correctly?  Did you copy it from some example documentation?

Comment: Did you install the packages you want to import? Can you [edit] your question and include all the steps you took, especially for installation? People should be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: pip list :google-cloud              0.34.0
google-cloud-dialogflow   2.25.0
google-cloud-language     2.11.1
google-cloud-texttospeech 2.14.2                                                                                              
python version 3.11.3                                                                                                                            I got help from bard artificial intelligence while writing the code.